# How to connect to Remote X server with docker?

Tags: docker, centos, xorg, xauth

I'm trying to connect to the remote server with docker. Basically, I need a real physical display to run GUI tests. Now, the issue is that the server doesn't have a physical Monitor so I'm trying to use X Forwarding to be able to connect to my PC with Monitor.

So what I've done so far:
On the machine with Monitor.

```
1) $ touch /tmp/.docker.xauth
2) $ xauth nlist $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f /tmp/.docker.xauth nmerge -
3) rsync -aztP /tmp/.docker.xauth user@server_in_clouds:/tmp/.docker.xauth
4) echo $DISPLAY (returns :1)
```

On the machine in Cloud.

```
1) docker run --rm -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /tmp/.docker.xauth:/tmp/.docker.xauth -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.docker.xauth --gpus=all -e DISPLAY=IP_OF_THE_MACHINE_WITH_MONITOR:1 -e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all DOCKER_IMAGE  xclock
```

After some time it says that it can't connect to the IP_OF_THE_MACHINE_WITH_MONITOR:1

Should I do anything else? I believe I'm missing something. Maybe it is not required to have a physical Monitor in centos in order to do so?

Comment: X servers by default haven't accepted remote TCP connections for a long long time now.

Comment: @DavidMaze you are actually correct, i tried to enable it but seems that it didn't help